# Rxjava2 - how to emit onNext() right away before observable sequence completes

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I have two observables that are chained together in a flatMap like this:

```
 override fun getProductObservable(): Observable<List<ProductModel>> {

return observable1(productId)
               .flatMap({
                 val limit = 8 - it.size
                   observable2(productId,  limit)
               }, { p1, p2 ->
                   p1.addAll(p2);  p1 //simply return observables1's results already packed with p2 results
               })
```

notice how observable2 depends on a result from observable1 (limit argument).  **BOTH OBSERVABLES RETURN THE SAME TYPE**

Now onto my question, i would like observable1 once complete to immediately call onNext of the subscriber but still carry on to the flatmap.  Essentially, the subscribers onNext would be called twice is what i want; *once* when observable1 completes and t*hen again* when the entire  call completes.  How can this be arranged ?

Answer (score 0):

Publish it and concatenate in the last value!

```
observable1(productId)
.publish( { shared ->
     Observable.concatArrayEager(
         shared.flatMap({
             val limit = 8 - it.size
               observable2(productId,  limit)
           }, { p1, p2 ->
               p1.addAll(p2);
           }),
         shared.takeLast(1)
     )
})
```

Comment: i could not make it work with concatEager but i used concat instead. but when i put a print statement in onNext it only fired once.

Comment: Updated the answer, use `concatArrayEager`.

Comment: what i see happening now is that in the subscriber its printing the last results twice. so essentially its returning the final result twice. i want it to return observable1 results in onNext and then afterwards return the final results. have you executed this ? maybe im missing something and thanks for showing me about concatArrayEager

Comment: How could I have executed it without knowing the definition of `observable1` and `observable2`, and possibly setting up the whole infrastructure and datasources behind them? Also your question said "the subscribers onNext would be called **twice**"; I interpreted this as you want the last item of `observable1` appear in the end output.

Comment: i put in bold that the observables have the same type. sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

i could not believe how easy it was. i used startWith and it emitted the results of the first observable. AFter a second the final results came through.   so it looks like this:

```
override fun getProductObservable(): Observable<List<ProductModel>> {

return observable1(productId)
               .flatMap({
                 val limit = 8 - it.size
                   observable2(productId,  limit)
                    .startWith(Observable.just(emptyList<ProductModel>()))
               }, { p1, p2 ->
                   p1.addAll(p2);  p1 //simply return observables1's results already packed with p2 results
               })
```